# Recording microphone audio only on iPad

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, ipad

Apologies if this has been asked before.

I currently use an iPad with iPadOS 16.6 and record audio using the built-in recording software on the iPad. Is there any way to be able to record *only* microphone audio from the iPad and leave out desktop audio? Specifically, when I perform a screen recording with microphone on, the microphone audio ends up too quiet in the recording. Are there any recording tools or apps that can leave out desktop audio completely, or if not possible, decrease the volume of it? I would also prefer if this was available as a recording app directly from the iOS App Store, although otherwise is still OK.